# Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous IN PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I need some help with my code. I have a trouble with connecting to the two different mysql database tables at the same time.

I'm getting an error: Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous IN PHP

Which it have highlight on this line:

```
$qrytable1="SELECT id, channels, links, categories, streams 
FROM channels_list
INNER JOIN chris_channels ON (chris_channels.channels = channels_list.channels)";
```

Here is the code:

```
$qrytable1="SELECT id, channels, links, categories, streams 
FROM channels_list
INNER JOIN chris_channels ON (chris_channels.channels = channels_list.channels)";
  $result1 = mysql_query($qrytable1) or die('Error:<br />' . $qry . '<br />' . mysql_error());

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) 
  {
    echo "<p id='channels'>".$row["id"]. " " . $row["channels"]. "</p>";
    echo "<p id='streams'>".$row["streams"]. "</p>";
  }
```

Can you please help me with how I could correct the error to allow me to connect to the mysql tables?

Comment: You have an `id` field in both tables. You need to specify which `id` you need, using something like: `channels_list.id` in your field list (or using table aliases)

Comment: Thank you very much for this, I can see the problem is fixed but I want to know how i could connect to two different mysql tables at the same time?

Comment: You are - that's what a `JOIN` does. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6188334/8469069) great answer to see how the different types work.

Comment: Don't use the `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated since v5.5 (Jun 2013) and removed since v7.0 (Dec 2015). Instead use the [**mysqli_***](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) functions with [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Answer (score 0):

Your entire code is deprecated as mentioned in the comment section above. Do **NOT** use `mysql()`. Use `mysqli()`. I'm even surprised that your IDE did not flag you on that.

Do this

```
$qrytable1="SELECT cl.id, cl.channels, cl.links, cl.categories, cl.streams 
FROM channels_list cl
LEFT JOIN chris_channels cc ON (cc.channels = cl.channels)";

  $result1 = mysqli_query($db, $qrytable1) 
  or die('Error:<br />' . $qry . '<br />' . mysqli_error());

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) 
  {
    echo "<p id='channels'>".$row["id"]. " " . $row["channels"]. "</p>";
    echo "<p id='streams'>".$row["streams"]. "</p>";
  }
```

Now replace `$db` for the database variable you are using to connect your application. I don't know what it is, I just used it as example.